# WFFM required validation is not working for dropdownlist field

Tags: wffm

I am working on Sitecore 8.1 rev. 151207 (Update-1) and using WFFM version 8.1 rev. 151217.

I have set the manual text and value in dropdownlist control in WFFM field and mark this field as "Required". But dropdownlist required validation is not working when I submit the form?

Do anybody know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

WFFM currently does not allow client side validation on dropdown list. You should use the client side validation using javascript. Remove the dropdown list from required in WFFM and set the client side validations for it.

Another workaround is to create the custom WFFM validation fields, you can follow this document for it.

https://sitecore.unic.com/2015/06/09/create-custom-validation-fields-in-sitecore-wffm